# Story where Puloman was killed by Indrani's future husband Indra?

Tags: ramayana, indra

As per [wiki/Shachi](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Shachi):

> Puloman, an Asura who was killed by **Indrani's future husband**, Indra.

But as per [UTTARA KANDA of Valmiki Ramayana](http://www.sacred-texts.com/hin/rys/rys7030.htm), Puloman (or Puloma) saves Jayanta (Indra's son) in Ravana/MeghnAdh - Indra war:

> पुत्रश च तव देवेन्द्र न विनष्टॊ महारणे
>
> नीतः संनिहितश चैव अर्यकेण महॊदधौ
>
> Thy son, O lord of Devas, hath not been destroyed in the conflict. He hath been taken into the ocean by his [maternal] grand father (Puloma).
>
> [image]

**What is the story where Puloman was killed by Indrani's future husband Indra? If Indra killed Puloma even before his marriage then how come Puloma saves Indra's son? Does someone bring Puloma's life back?**